# Calculate dates between Start and end dates in SQL using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-server-2016, datediff

I'm looking to calculate the number of days that overlap between to (DateTime) spans of time.

Logic behind the question is: A prisoner is serving a sentence from Orig bed start (beginning of his sentence) to Bed End Date (end of his sentence). During his sentence he took a leave of absence for whatever reason... idea is to calculate the numbers of days that specific prisoner took days off from his sentence as an example.

Making sure the leave start and end dates fall between the bed start and end days and then calculating the date difference and ignoring the rest.

Given this existing data:

| ORIG_BED_START | ORIG_BED_END | LEAVE_START_DAT | LEAVE_END_DATE | LEAVE_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-19 09:21:00.000 | 2022-11-02 14:49:00.000 | 2022-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2022-11-02 00:00:00.000 | ?? |
| 2022-11-02 14:50:00.000 | 2022-11-16 13:19:00.000 | 2022-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2022-11-02 00:00:00.000 | ?? |
| 2022-12-19 10:17:00.000 | 2022-12-27 10:59:00.000 | 2022-12-19 00:00:00.000 | 2022-12-30 00:00:00.000 | ?? |
| 2022-12-27 11:00:00.000 | NULL | 2022-12-19 00:00:00.000 | 2022-12-30 00:00:00.000 | ?? |
| 2022-12-22 20:29:00.000 | 2022-12-29 17:48:00.000 | 2022-12-26 00:00:00.000 | 2022-12-30 00:00:00.000 | ?? |
| 2022-12-29 17:49:00.000 | 2022-12-30 14:59:00.000 | 2022-12-26 00:00:00.000 | 2022-12-30 00:00:00.000 | ?? |

I am expecting the result set to be:

| ORIG_BED_START | ORIG_BED_END | LEAVE_START_DAT | LEAVE_END_DATE | LEAVE_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-19 09:21:00.000 | 2022-11-02 14:49:00.000 | 2022-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2022-11-02 00:00:00.000 | 5 |
| 2022-11-02 14:50:00.000 | 2022-11-16 13:19:00.000 | 2022-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2022-11-02 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 2022-12-19 10:17:00.000 | 2022-12-27 10:59:00.000 | 2022-12-19 00:00:00.000 | 2022-12-30 00:00:00.000 | 8 |
| 2022-12-27 11:00:00.000 | NULL | 2022-12-19 00:00:00.000 | 2022-12-30 00:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 2022-12-22 20:29:00.000 | 2022-12-29 17:48:00.000 | 2022-12-26 00:00:00.000 | 2022-12-30 00:00:00.000 | 4 |
| 2022-12-29 17:49:00.000 | 2022-12-30 14:59:00.000 | 2022-12-26 00:00:00.000 | 2022-12-30 00:00:00.000 | 0 |

This is the closest I have come

```
CASE 
    WHEN (CONVERT(DATE, LEAVE_START_DATE) >= CONVERT(DATE, ORIG_BED_START) AND 
          CONVERT(DATE, LEAVE_START_DATE) <= CONVERT(DATE, ORIG_BED_END)) 
         OR (CONVERT(DATE, LEAVE_END_DATE) >= CONVERT(DATE, ORIG_BED_END) AND CONVERT(DATE, LEAVE_END_DATE) <= CONVERT(DATE, ORIG_BED_END))
        THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, LEAVE_START_DATE, LEAVE_END_DATE)
        ELSE ''
END AS LEAVE_DAYS
```

Comment: Can you explain the desired logic here?

Comment: you have two columns with identical names - is that a typo

Comment: Typo Fixed.       Logic behind the question is: A prisoner started his sentence from Orig bed start to Bed End Date.  Between his sentence he took a leave of absence for whatever reason... idea is to calculate the numbers of days that specific prisoner took days off from his sentence as an example.

Comment: Your logic is not clear here. I don't understand the values in leave_days.

Answer (score 1):

The math to evaluate is MAX(0, MIN(orig_bed_end, leave_end_date) - MAX(orig_bed_start, leave_start_dat) ), in SQL that should give:

```
greatest(0, trunc( convert(date,least(coalesce(orig_bed_end,leave_end_date),leave_end_date)) - convert(date,greatest(orig_bed_start,leave_start_dat))))
```

Depending on where you will put the trunc - after or before calculating the difference - you may have slightly different results (+-1).

(quickly converted from ORACLE syntax, so may still need fixes to work in SQLServer)

Comment: This needs a lot more work before it can work in sql server. `LEAST` and `GREATEST` are available with sql server but not until 2022 which was just released. There is no direct translation for `TRUNC`.

Comment: for trunc(number): round(number,0,1) should do the work.

Comment: Take a look at https://dbfiddle.uk/lUF18TIo